# How to properly iterate through a char pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am in the process of learning C and I have this issue:

main:

```
int main()
{
    char str[] = "abcdefg";
    countRange(str, 'e');

}
```

function:

```
int countRange(char* str, char c1)
{
    char *t;
    for (t = str; *t != '\0'; t++)
    {
        if ((t >= c1))
        {
            printf(t);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the goal would be for the function to only print "efg", since those values are greater than or equal to the character e, however nothing ends up getting printed and the function exits. Can someone help me out? Thanks

Comment: It should be `if (*t >= c1)`. You forgot to dereference `t`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That got this to print: efgfgg , any idea why?

Comment: Yep, that's the output I would expect from your code, since you're printing the entire string from position `t` any time the first character of that string meets the criteria.

Comment: `printf(t)` is wrong as it expects a string as the first arg, so it will print the whole string starting from `t`. Change it to `putchar(*t)`.

Comment: `printf` does _NOT_ require a string literal for its format specifier.  Any string is fine.

Comment: @paddy, But not using a formatstring leaves you vulnerable unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: In addition to the previous comments, please note that your function should return an int but returns nothing. Change it to return `void` in its signature, or return an `int` if that's what you wanted. Your main as well should return an int, but there is no return statement.

Comment: The compiler should have warned you about problems in your code.

Comment: When I compile your code I get 2 warnings. Did you ignore the warnings? If so.. don't!! If you didn't get warnings, you need to increase the compilers warning level

Comment: First warning: `warning: comparison between pointer and integer: if ((t >= c1))` more or less tells you exactly where the bug is.... Don't ignore warnings

Comment: OT: The function name `countRange` is strange as the function doesn't do any counting

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am using CLion and am not seeing any warnings in my console log, anyone know how to enable them. I solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize. There are three things you should keep in mind.

1. Warnings in C are very important treat them like errors.
2. When dealing with pointers, derefrence to compare elements.
3. printf family of functions are a little different than other languages, see below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/**
  * Since the function returns nothing it returns `void`
  */
void countRange(char str[], char c1)
{
    char *t;
    for (t = str; *t != '\0'; t++)
    {
        if ((*t >= c1)) // *t refers to the char. using t would be the whole string
        {
            printf("%c", *t); // printf prints strings only
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "abcdefg";
    countRange(str, 'e');
}
```

Expanding on function signature, main is the only exception. That is the return statement is more or less optional.

The %c on the other hand simply tells the printf function that you are subbing in a character into that string, namely `*t`.